# Finding the square roots of large numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Let $n = pq$, where $$p = 13710221545914561761\\q = 11066328760152681859$$ are both primes.
Find the (two) square roots of $1 \pmod n$ that are $6= ±1 \pmod n$. Let the square roots be $a_1\pmod n$ and $a_2 \pmod n$, with $a_1, a_2 ∈ \{0, \cdot\cdot\cdot, n − 1\}$, and $a_1 > a_2$, nd $a_1$.

Comment: This is a clear attempt of cheating for the application to the *Summer Internship in Cryptology 2018*, *R C Bose Centre for Cryptology and Security, Indian Statistical Institute*.